# May one buy gold coins from wholesalers vs the retail dealers?

Tags: gold

I am interested in buying a lot of American Gold Eagle coins.  I live in Irvine CA.

The local gold dealers in my city tell me I should come into their store, bring them a check, and come back one week later to pick up the coins.

They say they need one week because they have to use my money to first buy the coins from their wholesalers, and resell to me at a large markup.

How can I find out who are the wholesalers?  Is there any way I could buy direct from them?

Comment: Try ebay, it is a great place to buy and sell precious coins.

Comment: You realize, you can buy these directly from the [US government](https://catalog.usmint.gov/coin-programs/american-eagle-coins/?prefn1=metalType&prefv1=gold&&cm_mmc=Google-_-Brand+-+Exact-_-US+Mint+-+Variations-_-usmint_g_&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5dW9s6Tm3wIViYnICh30BQqfEAAYASABEgJP7vD_BwE)

Comment: If I was selling, the guy counted out the cash and we swapped.  Or if buying, he'd have some inventory or obtain it and then we'd transact.  I'd be hesitant about giving any gold dealer a check and have to wait a week for delivery.  A long time ago I bought and sold Kruggerands for $10 above/below spot.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few large-volume retail bullion dealers that offer internet buying and selling. Just search for "bullion dealers" and size-them-up. Basically, gold coins can be bought retail at about 3.7% over spot or less and volume discounts are offered.

Wholesale gold buying would likely require regular volume buying. The wholesalers are refiners and government mints but the government mints are also retailers.

Now the Gold Eagles are available as collectible coins with mint-marks or available as bullion coins without mint-marks. And the collectible Gold Eagles are available as proof-coins or as un-circulated coins. Of course, new coins are available, certain-year coins are available, and random-year coins are available.